# Failure to create login script (Post 500 internal server error)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am having an issue with a brand new site I am trying to create, Its pretty basic right now, and I am just playing around with seeing how I like to do things.

So I have a place where I can log in currently, just two forms and a button. And I would like to use Ajax to call a php script that handles the login and then spits out a response depending on how it goes.

Here is what I have.

HTML:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="key-form" name="keyform" action="scriptLogin.php" method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="username">
 <input type="password" name="password">
 <input type="submit" class="button" value="Login">             
</form>
```

Ajax Call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#key-form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // stop normal form submission
        $.ajax({
            url: "scriptLogin.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).serialize(), // you also need to send the form data
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){ // this happens after we get results
                $("#response").show();
                $("#response").html("");

                // If there is no error the response will be {"success":true}
                // If there is any error means the response will be {"error":["1":"error",..]}
                if(data.success){
                    $("#response").prepend("<h3>Successfully Logged In</h3>");
                }else{
                    $.each(data.error, function(index, val){
                        $("#response").prepend("<h3>" +val+ '</h3>');
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

scriptLogin.php

```
<?php
session_start();
// Database configuration
// Not the real credentials obviously
define('DB_HOST', 'dbhost');
define('DB_USER', 'username');
define('DB_PASS', 'password');
define('DB_NAME', 'dbname');

// Initializing error array
$response['error'] = array();

try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST .';dbname=' . DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8mb4', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $response['error'][] = "Error in DB Connection";
}

// Store post and session values to variable.
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$key = $_POST['key'];

// Validating Password
if($password === '' || $password === FALSE ){
    $response['error'][] = "Your Password cannot be blank";
}
if($username === '' || $username === FALSE ){
    $response['error'][] = "Your Username is too short!";
}

// If validation password update the password for the user.
if(empty($response['error'])){
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Login WHERE username= :username"); // Prepare the query
 // Bind the parameters to the query
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
    //Carry out the query
    $stmt->execute();
    $hash = $stmt['hash'];

    $affectedRows = $stmt->rowCount(); // Getting affected rows count
    if($affectedRows != 1){
        $response['error'][] = "No User is related to the Username";
    }
    if(password_verify($password, $hash))
    {
      $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $stmt['ID'];
    }
    else
    {
      $response['error'][] = "Your password is invalid.";
    }
}

// printing response.
if(!empty($response['error'])){
    echo json_encode($response);
}else{
    echo json_encode(array("success"=>true));
}
?>
```

So whenever I try and log in. I get this error: 
POST http://website.net/scriptLogin.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

```
m.ajaxTransport.send    @   jquery.min.js:4
m.extend.ajax           @   jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous function)    @   (index):62
m.event.dispatch        @   jquery.min.js:3
m.event.add.r.handle    @   jquery.min.js:3
```

I need a shove in the correct direction. I checked the sites error page on cpanel. I have nothing for this. Im baffled.

EDIT #1:
Here is the error from loginScript.php

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in /home/mcomputers/public_html/key/scriptLogin.php:40 Stack trace: #0 /home/mcomputers/public_html/key/scriptLogin.php(40): PDOStatement->bindParam(':password', NULL) #1 {main} thrown in /home/mcomputers/public_html/key/scriptLogin.php on line 40
```

Comment: Use the *actual* error checking messages and check your error logs.

Comment: Could you be more specific on the how? OR atleast give me a link or something to google?

Comment: You're catching the exception `$e` but you're not getting any value from that, like the true error messages. For instance `$errorMsg = $e->getMessage();` On 500 errors you can look in your error logs (these are located in various places dependent upon your server).

Comment: Apologizes for my mistake. thanks for pointing.

Comment: When something like this happens to me and it's not obvious and there's nothing in the log, i just start at the top of my script and put `die('here');` on every line until it breaks. That way I know which line is causing the problem.

Comment: What happens when you just go to the PHP page directly in the browser?

Comment: I looked on the cpanel error logs for the errors, I got nothing there. Ill try and figure out how to display the errors on my page. Might take am a few.

Comment: @timgavin I havent tried that since I would have to rewrite things to get it to handle everything properly.

Comment: Yep. I have no idea how to do what you are asking @JayBlanchard. Is there something I am supposed to add?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I already had that on my main page, but I put it on my scriptLogin as well and now the thing doesnt work at all. Just does nothing, no errors, nothing.

Comment: @FrankEdgar no you wouldn't Just visit the script and see if you get the 500 error.

Comment: Comment everything in the file except for the error checking lines. If that loads OK (a blank file) then un-comment a line or a block at a time until it stops working.

Comment: Editted with the response after following both of your initial advice. I turned on error reporting and then I went directly to the script. Three errors saying undefined (Because there was no POST) and the forth being fatal (posted above)

Comment: The problem is somewhere in the if(empty($response['error'])){... code block.